# ordering street address in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm having some issues with a SQL query. I need to order the results of a select statement by street address.

I started with:

```
SELECT * FROM addressTable ORDER BY streetAddress ASC
```

but this would return

```
1 bob street 
10 bob street
2 bob street
```

To rectify this, I changed my statement to:

```
SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY LEN(StreetAddress), StreetAddress ASC
```

I thought this was ideal as it was now returning:

```
1 bob street
2 bob street
10 bob street
```

However I hadn't anticipated apartment and flat numbers, which are in the format of 1a 1b 210a 210b etc, so I found my query would return like so:

```
210 bob street
211 bob street
212 bob street
213 bob street
210a bob street
210b bob street
```

Instead of:

```
210 bob street
210a bob street
210b bob street
211 bob street
212 bob street
213 bob street
```

What is the simplest query I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Does the address always have street number?

Comment: the most simple is to split street name from house numbering information. The more complex is to make a sorting algorithm usually in a code layer and use that either to store a sort key or just sorting in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(LEFT(StreetAddress, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', StreetAddress)  - 1) AS INT),
         StreetAddress
```

The idea is to extract the leading number value, cast it to `INT`, sort by it, then sort by the field itself. It should work provided `StreetAddress` values are like the ones posted.