# sorting string and numeric mix values in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have data in varchar some times number and some times text.
I want to sort this from 0 to 100 and A to Z in grouping but it returns 10,11,...2 it works proper with text i.e A,B,C...

Is there any solution for this I am using report builder 2014.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected result.

Comment: Have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883693/ordering-street-address-in-ms-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
;WITH Tbl(val) AS(
    SELECT '1' UNION ALL
    SELECT '10' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2' UNION ALL
    SELECT '3' UNION ALL
    SELECT '15' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'E' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'F' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Z'
)
SELECT *
FROM Tbl
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN val NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN val NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN CAST(val AS INT) END,
    val
```

---

`NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` will return false if `val` contains non-numeric character.

Answer (score 0):

Add three sorting parameters to group properties:

Sort by: `=CInt(IIF(Fields!ID.Value like "[0-9]*", 0, 1))` [A to Z] sorting

Then by: `=CInt(IIF(Fields!ID.Value like "[0-9]*", Fields!ID.Value, 1))` [A to Z] 
sorting

Then by: `=Fields!ID.Value` [A to Z] sorting